# get values out of a for loop

Tags: php, html

I am writing a php code for examination mgt module and i need to give the number of students that are on probation, withdrawn, deficient or in good standing which is after i have calculated the previous cgpa, the cumulative cgpa and also if the students have carry over courses or not. all this are in a for loop and i want to get the result out of the for loop. how do i do that. my code is lengthy below

i have edited the code to that what i want to achieve can be understood

```
foreach($aitemn as $item) {
    if ( substr($item,1,2) < 13 || (substr($item,1,2) == 13 && $mode == '2')) {

        if ($pcgpa < 1.0 && $gpa < 1.0 && $xlevel == 1) {
            $remark = 'Probation';
            $p = $p + 1;
        }
        elseif ($pcgpa < 1.0 && $gpa < 1.0 && $xlevel != 1) {
            $remark = 'Withdraw';
            $w = $w + 1;
        }
        elseif($gpa > 1.0 &&  $fc == 'NIL')  {
            $remark = 'In Good Standing'; 
            $gs = $gs + 1;
        }
        elseif ( $gpa < 1.0 && $pcgpa > 1.0) {
            $remark = 'Probation';
            $p = $p + 1;
        }      
        elseif ($fc <> 'NIL' ) {
            $remark = 'Deficient';
            $d = $d + 1;
        }
    }
    elseif (substr($item,1,2) > 12) {   

        if ($pcgpa < 1.5 && $gpa < 1.5 && $xlevel == 1) {
            $remark = 'Probation';
            $p = $p + 1;
        }
        elseif ($pcgpa < 1.5 && $gpa < 1.5 && $xlevel != 1) {
            $remark = 'Withdraw';
            $w = $w + 1;
        }
        elseif($gpa > 1.5 &&  $fc == 'NIL') {
            $remark = 'In Good Standing'; 
            $gs = $gs + 1;
        }
        elseif ( $gpa < 1.5 && $pcgpa > 1.5) {
            $remark = 'Probation';
            $p = $p + 1;
        }      
        elseif ($fc <> 'NIL' ) {
            $remark = 'Deficient';
            $d = $d + 1;
        }
    }

    $num = $num + 1;
}


<td>Number in Good Standing: <?php echo $gs;?></br>
<td>Number on Probation:     <?php echo $p;?></br>
<td>Number in Deficient      <?php echo $d;?></br>
<td>Number in Withdrawn      <?php echo $w;?></br>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: i have a a list of students that i am calculating their GPA, CGPA , PCGPA and if they have carry overs or not. all these are in a for loop. i now need to print the number of students that have outstanding courses, number of students that are in good standing etc. i noticed that the variables cannot be accessed outside the for loop even after using an array.

Comment: I'll suggest you re-write your code, such that there are conditions that meet the criteria students that 1. have outstanding courses, 2. are in good standing, etc. That way, it makes your code less ambiguous and easy to understand.

Comment: hi Samuel. thanks. i have reduced the core code to show what i want to achieve below but it seems i cant add the code again

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to echo out the result number of students in 1. Good Standing, 2. on Probation, 3. in Deficient, 4. in Withdrawn.. from the overall total number of students, right? If so, _1. What criteria makes a student in good standing?_ _2. What criteria makes a student on probation?_ _3. What criteria makes a deficient student?_ and _4. What criteria makes a student withdrawn?_ If you can answer these questions, you're good to go.

Comment: yes all the criteria are known. actually the full programme writes oustanding courses etc for each student but i now want to give a summary of the number of students that met each of the criteria

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I understand what you mean.

In order for you to access the variables in your `foreach` loop, one way to do that will be for you to **nest** your markup within the loop like so:

```
<?php
foreach( $aitemn as $item ) {
    // your other codes
?>
<td>Number in Good Standing: <?php echo $gs;?></br>
<td>Number on Probation:     <?php echo $p;?></br>
<td>Number in Deficient      <?php echo $d;?></br>
<td>Number in Withdrawn      <?php echo $w;?></br>

<?php
} // close the foreach after the markup
?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks samuel but really it is the last values of each that i want to see and not all the iterations of each variable

Comment: Last values, you mean where you have added `+ 1` to the variables?